# Why does $Y$ turn into $X$ distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

[image]

[image]

I have 1 question regarding the answer to this exercise:

1)why does Y turn to X in the second row? Are we allowed to do this?

If somebody could clarify this for me, that would really help

Comment: Well, $Y = ZX$ and in the first probability Z = 1 and in the second Z = -1. So Y = X in the first case, Y = -X in the second. Just plug that in.

Comment: ohh, okay, thanks, this completely went over my head...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second row, $Y$ can be replaced by $X$ because when $Z=1,$ then $Y$ and $X$ are equal. And the reason it is done is to get an event that is the intersection of two independent events: $X\le y$ and $Z=1.$

And $Y= -X$ when $Z=-1.$